# BigQuery - Delete based on values from another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to delete rows from one table, based on the second table using INNER JOIN on BigQuery, but it keeps giving error.

The context is simple, I have an input table that I'm fetching the dates contained there, and on the historic table, I want to delete those dates in order to put them after the delete.

The code that I have now is the following, however it's returning the error

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword INNER at [3:1]

```
DELETE
FROM `datapool-prt-supplychain-wrk.TRANSPORTS_DATA.tbl_historico_tb_rota` AS a 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT 
        CAST(
            CONCAT(RIGHT(data,4),'-',
                CASE 
                    WHEN LENGTH(data) = 8 THEN 
                        CONCAT('0',SUBSTR(data ,3,1),'-0',LEFT(data ,1))
                    WHEN LENGTH(data) = 9 AND SUBSTR(data,3,1) = "-" THEN 
                        CONCAT('0',SUBSTR(data ,4,1),"-",LEFT(data ,2))
                    WHEN LENGTH(data) = 9 THEN 
                        CONCAT(SUBSTR(data ,3,2),'-0',LEFT(data ,1))
                    WHEN LENGTH(data) = 10 THEN 
                        CONCAT(SUBSTR(data,4,2),'-',LEFT(data,2))
                    ELSE '1900-01-01'
                END
            )
        AS DATE ) AS data 
FROM `datapool-prt-supplychain-wrk.TRANSPORTS_DATA.tbl_input_tb_rota`) AS b ON b.data = a.data
WHERE b.data IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hello @JaimeDrq first thank you for your comment!
Could you detail more what do you mean? I couldn't understand.

Comment: Sorry André, I didn't see well your query and I was wrong in 2 of my recommendations. I have added an aswer with what I mean with exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your `join` logic to an `exists` clause

```
delete from `datapool-prt-supplychain-wrk.TRANSPORTS_DATA.tbl_historico_tb_rota` AS a 
where exists (
    select 1 
    from `datapool-prt-supplychain-wrk.TRANSPORTS_DATA.tbl_input_tb_rota` b
    where
      CAST(  
        CONCAT(
          RIGHT(b.data,4),'-',
          CASE 
            WHEN LENGTH(b.data) = 8 THEN 
              CONCAT('0',SUBSTR(b.data ,3,1),'-0',LEFT(b.data ,1))
            WHEN LENGTH(b.data) = 9 AND SUBSTR(b.data,3,1) = "-" THEN 
              CONCAT('0',SUBSTR(b.data ,4,1),"-",LEFT(b.data ,2))
            WHEN LENGTH(b.data) = 9 THEN 
              CONCAT(SUBSTR(b.data ,3,2),'-0',LEFT(b.data ,1))
            WHEN LENGTH(b.data) = 10 THEN 
              CONCAT(SUBSTR(b.data,4,2),'-',LEFT(b.data,2))
            ELSE '1900-01-01'
          END
        )
      AS DATE ) = a.data
      )
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! 
I need to remove the "where b.data IS NOT NULL" in order to work, but it works perfectly! 
You saved me many hours, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, you were totally right, I kept that filter just by copy paste from your query but indeed it make no sense. I have removed it from the answer.